# lambda expression with nullable value - always false since the value of type Guid is never equal to 'null'

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public Guid? OwnersId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to fetch all car data upon criteria

```
List<Car> cars = await carsContext.Query(x=>x.Id== model.CarId && x.OwnersId.Value == null);
```

> The result of the expression is always false since the value of type
> Guid is never equal to 'null' of type 'Guid?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Value` property of [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-6.0) struct returns value of the underlying type (`Guid` in your case) which can not be `null`. Compare the `OwnersId` itself to null:

```cs
List<Car> cars = await carsContext
    .Query(x => x.Id == model.CarId && x.OwnersId == null);
```

Another option is to check `HasValue` property:

```cs
List<Car> cars = await carsContext
    .Query(x => x.Id == model.CarId && !x.OwnersId.HasValue);
```

Though if this will translate into valid SQL depends on the ORM you are using.

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting empty results set, although I know for sure when checking into db that this is not the case

Comment: @user1765862 have you checked the generated sql?

Comment: @user1765862 what ORM are you using and what is `Query` method?

Answer (score 1):

The 'Value' property will never be null. If the OwnersId is null then calling .Value would throw an exception. You should check against HasValue. So you can do this:

```
List<Car> cars = await carsContext.Query(x=>x.Id== model.CarId && !x.OwnersId.HasValue);
```